# Strange RewriteRule causes errors

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop, litespeed

I use PrestaShop on Litespeed server, here is a part of .htaccess of admin panel:

```
    # Keep legacy entry points
    RewriteRule ^(ajax|ajax_products_list|ajax-tab|backup|cron_currency_rates)\.php - [P]
    RewriteRule ^(displayImage|drawer|footer\.inc|functions|get-file-admin)\.php - [P]
    RewriteRule ^(grider|header\.inc|init|login|password|pdf|searchcron)\.php - [P]

    # If the URL is a legacy on index.php?controller=..., do not rewrite (let the legacy take it)
    RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)controller=|(^|&)tab=
    RewriteRule .* - [P]
```

I see many logs regarding those:

```
2021-10-30 16:01:17.163186  WARN    [225891] [T0] [REWRITE] Detects bad proxy action without updating target URL. Ignore. while parsing: RewriteRule ^(ajax|ajax_products_list|ajax-tab|backup|cron_currency_rates)\.php - [P]
2021-10-30 16:01:17.163218  WARN    [225891] [T0] [REWRITE] Detects bad proxy action without updating target URL. Ignore. while parsing: RewriteRule ^(displayImage|drawer|footer\.inc|functions|get-file-admin)\.php - [P]
2021-10-30 16:01:17.163228  WARN    [225891] [T0] [REWRITE] Detects bad proxy action without updating target URL. Ignore. while parsing: RewriteRule ^(grider|header\.inc|init|login|password|pdf|searchcron)\.php - [P]
2021-10-30 16:01:17.163243  WARN    [225891] [T0] [REWRITE] Detects bad proxy action without updating target URL. Ignore. while parsing: RewriteRule .* - [P]
2021-10-30 16:01:17.581695  WARN    [225890] [T0] [REWRITE] Detects bad proxy action without updating target URL. Ignore. while parsing: RewriteRule .* - [P]
```

Can anyone describe what are those RewriteRules and why I get those errors?

Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteRule .* - [P]`   P flag requires  pattern target  , you only have one like , it should be `RewriteRule foo bar [P]`   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Comment: @qtwrk Although it is the use of the `P` flag itself that is the error here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the `P` flag is clearly an error in this context. I would have said  it was a typo, was it not on every rule! They probably meant to use `PT` (passthrough), although `L` (last) (or `END`) would be preferable.

The purpose of these directives is to prevent further processing (ie. other rewrites from occurring) of these particular "legacy" URLs.

Change `[P]` to `[L]` on all 4 of these rules to resolve this.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

(Also changing `.*` to `^` on the last rule, since it doesn't need to actually match everything, it just needs to be successful for everything.)

Comment: just curious , what's difference between `.*` and `^`  ?

Comment: @qtwrk Efficiency (in this context). The regex `.*` steps through the entire URL-path and matches everything, storing this in a backreference that is later accessible with `$0`. The `^` (start-of-string anchor) simply asserts the start of string. It matches nothing (no backreferences are created), but is always successful.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! It was much more than enough and also learned many things about this.